# Extra array does not consume memory in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory

In Java, why this

```
int n = 100000;
int[] array = new int[n + n / 2];
int[] arrayzip = new int[n];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, arrayzip, 0, n);
hashmap.put(x, arrayzip);
```

and this

```
int n = 100000;
int[] array = new int[n + n / 2];
hashmap.put(x, new int[n]);
System.arraycopy(array, 0, hashmap.get(x), 0, n);
```

take the same amount of memory? In the first code sample an extra array is created.

**[EDIT]** Alright, now the second question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int n = 100000;
    int[] array = new int[n + n / 2];
    int[] arrayzip = new int[n];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, arrayzip, 0, n);
    hashmap.put(x, arrayzip);
}
```

What if we put any sample of code inside a loop, then `arrayzip` is created `100` times and then all `100` references are gone due to being scoped in a loop. Aaa, now I understand, so objects `new int[]` are created on the heap but they are not lost (garbage collected) because they stored their references in a out-of-scope object `hashmap`. Cool, I understand!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, both samples create the same number of arrays - 2. They both contain the following array creation expressions:

```
new int[n + n / 2]
new int[n]
```

Where did you think another array was being created? Or had you not spotted the array creation expression in the second case, within this statement:

```
hashmap.put(x, new int[n]);
```

The fact that in the first version the reference to one of them is assigned to a local variable makes *no* difference in terms of how many objects are created.

(I'd personally *vastly* prefer the first code over the second, by the way. It's much simpler to understand, IMO.)

Comment: So `hashmap.put(x, arrayzip)` stores reference of `arrayzip` and does not make a (is it called deep?) copy of it (pass by value)?

Comment: @SophieSperner: Yes. In Java *all* arguments are passed by value - but every value is only either a primitive or a reference, never an object. This isn't really about arrays - it's argument passing and the type system in general. It's *definitely* worth making sure you understand the way that works - if you're learning Java from a book, read that section really, really carefully.